# Is $X^2$ independent from $XY$ where $X$ and $Y$ are standard normals?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm thinking they can somehow be expressed as functions of $X-Y$ and $X+Y$, but I haven't quite found out how.

Bonus questions:

- Is it correct that they are both Chi square distributed?
- And so, would $X^2 + XY$ also be Chi square distributed?
- What would be the distribution of $a(X_0^2+Y_0^2) + b(X_0X_1+Y_0Y_1)$?

Comment: $XY$ follows a scaled normal distribution, _not_ a chi-square.

Comment: @probablyme That is super interesting. I thought $4XY = (X+Y)^2-(X-Y)^2$ showed that it was Chi squared?

Comment: Chi-square is a positive variable; $XY$ is symmetric around zero, so it cannot be chi-squared. Your equation just goes to show that the difference of two chi-squares is not necessarily chi-square.

Comment: If $X^2$ and $XY$ were independent, then $U=X^2$ and $V=X^2Y^2$ would be independent. But $E(UV)=E(X^4)E(Y^2)=3$ while $E(U)E(V)=E(X^2)^2E(Y^2)=1$ hence they are not.

Comment: It's simpler than that. $XY|X^2\sim \sqrt {X^2}N(0,1)$, so they are clearly dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independently $Norm(0, 1),$ and
define $Q = X^2$ and $T = XY.$

The following simulation suggests that $Cor(Q, T) = 0,$
and clearly shows that $Q$ and $T$ are not independent.

```
 m = 10^5;  x = rnorm(m);  y = rnorm(m)
 q = x^2;  t = x*y
 cor(q,t)
 ## 0.00575081  # consistent with 0 correlation
 plot(q, t, pch=".")
 abline(h = 5, col="green2", lwd=2)
 abline(v = 2, col="green2", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The figure seems to show that $P(Q < 1) > 0,\,$
and $P(T > 7) > 0,\,$ but $P(Q < 1, T > 7) \approx 0.$
I guess something like this may be simple to prove
rigorously.

Also, it seems clear that $T$ is not chi-squared
because it takes both positive and negative values.

[image]

You also have some useful hints in the comments.

Comment: Great idea to sample the density for intuition! However I'm not sure the 'check the corner' approach is very safe. If I just plotted $X$ and $Y$, I would probably see the same effect :)

Comment: Thanks. As a start nibbling at the corner, $P(Q < 1) =  P(|X| < 1) = 0.6826895$. Then how about $P(T > 7|Q < 1)$?